# Merging application icon into .exe file

Tags: wine, application

I'm using WineHQ on **Debian 10** and it is running totally fine with many Windows programs. However Wine cannot show the right application icon (it always shows only a generic icon for `.exe` applications).

I wonder if there is a way to restore the right icon or if there is a way to permanently link another icon to this particular program.

*For example, I'm playing FO2 and it would be cool to link `.exe` file to the icon which is stored in the same folder and every time I move the game to another directory it will keep the same icon.*

I had the same problem with `.mp3` files where I wanted to change the default audio icon. I solved that with program called `Puddletag` which merges images into the original `.mp3` file. Is there something similar for `.exe` programs?

Answer (score 0):

Windows applications typically already have icons embedded in the `.exe` files; what’s missing here is probably a program to extract the icons and make corresponding thumbnails.

Installing the `exe-thumbnailer` package should fix this.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already exe-thumbnailer installed. I've found out, that if you use Play on Linux to install applications, you can create shortcut, which looks like this: `env WINEPREFIX="/home/user/.wine" wine c:\\app\\app.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Did not test yet, however, as an alternative to Stephen's answer (`exe-thumbnailer` is suggested to `wine` package), could create a .desktop shortcut with icon property, exported with `icoutils` package and e.g. manual prefix.

```
$ wrestool -x -t 14 app.exe > "$HOME/.icons/app.ico"
```

```
$ cat > ~/app.desktop << EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Name=An App
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine" wine-stable 'C:\Program Files (x86)\...\app.exe'
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path="$HOME/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/..."
Icon="$HOME/.icons/app.ico"
StartupWMClass=app.exe
EOF
```

```
$ chmod +x ~/app.desktop
```

Comment: Thank You! My problem is solved!

I analyzed one of the `.desktop` launcher from PlayOnLinux.

Then I have created a new `application.desktop` file in text editor and pasted there the following code:



`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/user/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/user/application.exe
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/user
Icon=/home/user/icon.png
StartupWMClass=Application.exe`